# Count Undefined with MongoDB and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**Problem**

Node.js MongoDB library consistently returns undefined for `collection.count({})`. This question has been posted and answered numerous times, and I've been sure to go through all previous solutions, but none seem to work, and I *always* get undefined.

As a background to the question, I am making a Job Automator, and before adding a new job, I want to make sure that 0 records already exist in the database that have the same name as the new job being added (i.e. names are unique). **EDIT**: There are a few cases where I do want to allow duplicates, so I don't want using indexing and dis-allow duplicates at the DB level.

**Code**

In this case, the `console.log()` inside `count` just prints undefined. In this case, I have put in an empty query string as part of debugging (not currently testing for name collisions).

```
add: function(io, newJob)
    {
    //mc is where require('mongodb').MongoClient is saved
    //connectionString contains a valid connection string
    //activeCollection contains the name of the collection
    //(I am sure mc, connectionString and activeCollection are valid)
    //I know this as I have used them to insert documents in previous parts
    mc.connect(connectionString, function(err,db)
        {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        else
            {
            db.collection(activeCollection, function(err,collection)
                {
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                //Start of problematic part
                //See also "What I've tried" section
                collection.count({},function(err,count)
                    {
                    console.log(count);
                    });
                //End of problematic part
                //Omitting logic where I insert records for brevity,
                //as I have confirmed that works previously.
                });
            }
        db.close();
        });
    }
```

**What I've tried**

I've read the previous questions, and replaced the content between `//Start of problematic part` and `//End of problematic part` in the previous code block with the following blocks:

Fully breaking out the callback (also prints undefined):

```
function countDocs(callback)
    {
    collection.count({},function(err, count)
        {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        callback(null, count);
        }
    }

countDocs(function(err,count)
    {
    if(err)
        throw err;
    console.log(count);
    });
```

I've even tried things I know wouldn't work

```
var count = collection.count({});
```

**NEW (1/28/16)**

It was a little sloppy of me to not check the error in my `count()`, so I added a `if(err)console.log(err);` into the `count()` block and it turns out the error is:

```
{ [MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed] 
name: 'MongoError', 
message: 'server localhost 27017 sockets closed' }
```

Which I don't really understand because in other sections of code, I am able to use the same connect() and collection() calls and make inserts into the DB just fine. Any insight based on this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Added error checking to the count block, and turns out there is a peculiar error. Edited the original post to reflect that (see bottom of post).

Answer (score 1):

Let's deal with the intent of the question:

> I am making a Job Automator, and before adding a new job, I want to
>   make sure that 0 records already exist in the database that have the
>   same name as the new job being added (i.e. names are unique).

Rather than labor through javascript, just [set a unique index](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on the name key. In mongo:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { name: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Then when you insert a document use a try/catch block to catch any attempt to create a document with a duplicate name.

Comment: That helps! Still though, it would be nice to know how to reliably retrieve records from the DB, so hopefully we can answer that. Additionally, there may be a few edge cases where I want to allow duplicates, so I don't want to dis-allow that at the DB level. Sorry, should have mentioned that as part of the background, but left out for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collection.find().toArray(function(err,documents) { ...});`, which returns an empty array if no documents match your query.  Checking the `length` property of the array should be equivalent to what you are trying to achieve with `count()`.

More info in the docs: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toArray

Comment: This is amongst the things I've tried, but I get a similar issue: "cannot read property 'length' of undefined". documents is undefined so there is no length property.